# JSF - Reload page from Java Code (Java EE + RESTful)

Tags: java, jsf, post, web

I would like to refresh my JSF page on a post action from my Java code :

```
  @POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String handlePostRequest(String payload) { 
//some code

//here resfresh the JSF
     }
```

Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just declare a `<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.someAction}" value="Some action" />` and the page will be refreshed when `MyBean#someAction` returns an empty String.

Comment: Based in your edit, have you tried to add at the end of your method `return "";` and check if the pages refresh? Also, take note that your commandButton should not have any ajax function to refresh the whole page.

Comment: Your question is terribly formulated. You seem to be completely new to web development and not yet fully understand the basic concepts and terminology. Aren't you *actually* asking how to perform HTTP or ajax push?

Comment: BalusC is right ! I don't know how to formulate my question ! I want the page to refresh by itselft when my java code received information ! I'm going to take a look at what you said about ajax push ! thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple, to create a JSF page you need the following:

1. `<h:form />` : to include your page code
2. `<h:commandButton />` : to post the request to the server

Now to refresh:
Declare your button in the following way:

```html
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.refreshAction}" value="Refresh Action" />
```

The page will be refreshed when `MyBean#refreshAction` method returns an empty String to the server, that is when you fire the command button's event.

Comment: Thanks but I want to reload my page when my @POST methode run (in the java) code. I've something like that :
public String handlePostRequest(String payload) {
}
I post something on it with JSON from a Android device. I want the page to refresh when this method receive something. is it possible ?

Comment: Hm.. why not?? or did you find any other option?

Comment: No :( Nothing happen ! My method is called and return null.
I put the code you told me !
The page does not refresh ! Maybe with ajax...

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in your managed bean. Let it return null.Call the method with `<h:commandButton /> or <h:commandLink />`.This will refresh your page.

Comment: Thanks but I want to reload my page when my @POST methode run (in the java) code.
I've something like that :

Comment: public String handlePostRequest(String payload) {
}
I post something on it with JSON from a Android device. I want the page to refresh when this method receive something. is it possible ?